# Permitir conexão externa com o banco de dados

Tags: laravel, postgresql, linux, ubuntu

Pessoal tenho um problema para acessar um banco de dados que está em uma `Virtual Machine`.

Tenho uma máquina `A` que tem um aplicação `Laravel` todo configurado e o projeto instalado, e tem outra maquina `B` onde está o meu banco de dados, que também que está configurado.

No arquivo `.env` está usando as configurações padrões da VM.
Li uns tutorias para liberar o acesso ao banco, dentro do arquivo `pg_hba.conf` e o arquivo `postgresql.conf`. Nesses arquivos fiz o padrão para liberar o acesso, mas quando acesso o na máquina `A` e executo o comando `php artisan migrate` aparece um erro e `connection timeout` e não consigo me conectar ao banco de dados.

Qual a solução possivel para isso ?

Comment: E quais foram as modificações que você fez no `pg_hba.conf` e no `postgresql.conf` especificamente com este intuito?

Comment: 1 . no arquivo `/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf` 
`#listen_addresses = 'localhost' ` para `listen_addresses = '*' `





2 . no arquivo `/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/pg_hba.conf` adicione seguinte linha no finaçl do arquivo 
`host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`

Comment: Ai com essas configurações era para ter acesso remoto.

Comment: Recarregou os arquivos de configuração? Por exemplo com: `select pg_reload_conf();`.

Comment: Acho que não, vou verificar.

Comment: Como eu faria isso ?

Comment: Eu fiz o `service postgres restart`

Comment: Deu certo, era apenas o ip do servidor que estava errado, dei um `sudo ifconfig`.